# How dose Kafka offset change when redeploying SCDF stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

I use `SCDF on YARN 1.0.2.RELEASE` with `Kafka 0.10.0` for stream applications.

When I undeploy a stream and then deploy it again, it seems sometimes it continues at the current Kafka topic offset, while sometimes it starts from the oldest offset.

Where can I configure to get an predictable behavior(e.g. current offset,latest offset,oldest offset) when redeploying a stream?

Is there a way to expect different behavior for different stream?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.startOffset` to `latest` when redeploying the stream. The default behavior is to use `earliest`. You can see [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_kafka_consumer_properties) documentation for more info.

Comment: It seems that if the `resetOffsets` is `false`, the `startOffset` option will have no effect. Does the default `false`value of `resetOffsets` mean the consumer will start from where it left (the committed offset in Kafka)?

Comment: I believe this issue is addressed in this PR: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pull/146

Comment: What is the exact meaning of `latest`? Does it mean the latest offset in commit log or the latest offset in the partition?

Comment: Each partition is a commit log, isn't it?

Comment: I also came across a discussion at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/67. It seems there are still problems when a consumer has multiple instances?

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not describe it clearly. By saying ''each partition is a commit log", I think you mean Kafka's log files which store the real message. What I intended to describe is the offset commit logs under `__consumer_offsets-XX` directory which record consumed message offset in each topic partition. After further study, I now know the default setting is restarting from where it left. So, I think `latest` must mean that the program will skip some unconsumed message and read the newest incoming message.